# ubuntu does not boot up, wrong fstab

Tags: boot, 18.04, lubuntu, fstab

my computer with ubuntu 18.04 does not boot up, I can access the root shell I tried with boot-repair, this is the report on pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Jy4vgz95VD/,
my computer is a Sony vaio: Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8
this is my fstab:

```
# <device>                             
<dir> <type> <options> <dump> <fsck>
UUID=759fe52e-3cd0-4d0d-8b2a-0a5c094d9ef9 / ext4 default 0 1
```

Comment: You have older BIOS/MBR install with one large / (root) partition. But all the UUIDs seem to match and reinstall of grub worked without issue. If you hold shift key from BIOS screen do you get grub menu. And can you boot older kernel or recovery mode?

Comment: I can boot recovery mode

Comment: Then it often is some issue related to GUI? Are you getting error messages. At terminal with Internet can you update system? `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`  Or just start system from there?

Comment: It Is not possibile enabling the network,already tried nomodeset

Comment: So is network not working? Using WiFi or Ethernet?

Comment: Network Is not working in recovery mode

Comment: You need to resolve network issue first.

Comment: What have you tested? Does live installer work on both WiFi and Ethernet? Or do you then have a hardware issue?

Comment: Yes ,live Ubuntu Is working,never had any issues with network